# В заданной строке удалить второй и четвертый по счету символы

Tags: c++

Как я понимаю нужно удалить символы, а потом нужно сместить строку на количество удаляемых символов. Объясните алгоритм смещения на словах, что нужно сделать сначало

Comment: Из вашего вопроса не ясно, то ли вы хотите удалить символы из символьного массива или из объекта std::string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::string str = "12345";
str.erase(str.begin() + 3);
str.erase(str.begin() + 1);
std::cout << str << std::endl;
```

Удалит второй и четвертый

```
std::string str = "12345";
    std::string newStr;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
    {
        if (i != 1 && i != 3) // тут если вариантов много переделать
            newStr += str[i];
    }
    std::cout << newStr << std::endl;
```

Comment: А что делает erase?

Comment: Очевидно убирает элемент из последовательности

Comment: Это слишком просто, я бы хотел циклом, только не понимаю как это сделать. Вы можите на словах объяснить

Comment: добавил в ответ

Comment: А слишком просто — это плохо?

Comment: Простое всегда лучше сложного.

Comment: @АлексейМальченко: И я ж о чём.

Comment: Нужно понимать всё. Я только начал изучать плюсы, программирование как в целом, и до векторов я не дошёл ещё

Comment: Начни с книги по алгоритмам

Comment: Посоветуй автора

Comment: Ну по классике Кнута почитай. Д. Кнут "Искусство программирования"

Comment: Как вариант можете попробовать перебрать все элементы массива и переложить в новый массив все элементы поочередно которые не 2 и 4 к примеру. Если циклом, но это колено!

Comment: Я этот пример и предложил ему в добавок к нормальному варианту

Answer (score 1):

Удалить циклом? В том числе по месту? Тривиально.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


// C-style
void del24 (char *dst, char *src) {
  int i = 0, j = 0;

  for (; src[i]; i++) 
    if (!(i == 2 || i == 4))
      dst[j++] = src[i];
  dst[j] = 0;
}


int main()
{
  string str("1234567");

    cout << str << '\n';

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < str.size(); i++) 
      if (!(i == 2 || i == 4))
        str[j++] = str[i];

    str.resize(str.size() - 2);
    cout << str << '\n';

    del24((char *)str.c_str(), (char *)str.c_str());
    str.resize(str.size() - 2);
    cout << str << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

На любой вкус.

Comment: Вроде бы [`c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) возвращает `const char*`, так что второй способ наверное не подойдёт.

Comment: Реально (Linux, g++) это работает (только приведение типа для компайлера нужно).

Comment: Я вот боюсь, что на каком-нибудь уровне оптимизации компилятор возьмёт и предположит, что `const char` никогда не меняется, и воспользуется этим. Или например при оптимизации реально выкинет `std::string`, а строковую константу расположит в память только для чтения.

Comment: Тогда (после падения) код украситcя очередным ifdef-ом...

Comment: @VladD, тем более это просто демонстрация "алгоритма" по удалению чего-либо (например, пробелы или звездочки или дубликаты в отсортированном массиве) из массива за один проход и без дополнительной памяти. (Надеюсь, ТС это понял).