# Удалить первое слово заданной строки. Разделителем слов считается пробел

Tags: c++

```
char str[80] = "faE,1*fe A.,.3iBVf Oq. e.of 43G.FW2,jiq,e[ qe";
char token[80];

char *p = str;
char *t = token;

cout << str << endl;    

//находим индекс первого пробела.
int index = 0;
while (*p){
    if (*p == ' '){
        index = p - str;
        break;
    }       
    ++p;
}

//копируем всё, что за пределами 1-ого пробела (по индексу), как я понимаю
while (*p){
    if (*p != index){
        *t = *p;
        ++t;
    }
    ++p;
}   
*t = 0;

cout << token << endl;
```

Как объединить этих 2 цикла в одни, что бы находил индекс пробела и копировал, в одном while-ле?

Comment: А зачем? код станет менее читаемый, добавятся переменные и условия, будут выполняться ненужные действия

Comment: То есть, такой код в пол не сойдёт?

Comment: конечно, сам по себе он кривой и некрасивый, но если работает, то подход правильный. но мне кажется, он просто не работает. я не прав?

Comment: Вроде работает. Обоснуйте, пожалуйста, свою точку зрения, почему?

Comment: ну, например, потому что ты указатель сравниваешь со смещением. этот иф всегда тру :) может, повезло и работает :)

Comment: не знаю, у меня работает и результат выполнения, я считаю правильным

Comment: Я уже си не помню, но как-то так должно быть while (*p && (*p++ != ' ') ; do *t++ = *p++; while (*p++);

Comment: @Ilya Tikhonov Возникают вопросы к заданию. Например, 1)что делать, если строка начинается с пробелов? 2) Если между словами несколько пробелов, в этом случае в выходную строку нужно также копировать ведущие пробелы? 3) Можно ли использовать стандартные функции?

Comment: 3) можно strcpy, кажется, так называется. Остальное от тз зависит. Для 2 поставь еще цикл, пока пробелы

Comment: Вы рассуждаете как профессионал, я пока осваиваю озы програмирования

Comment: @IlyaTikhonov, а Вы ответы (и комментарии к ним) на [свои же предыдущие вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/429940/%D0%92-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B/429990#429990) анализируете?

Comment: Кстати, примерно на эту тему можете посмотреть http://pastebin.com/vFQNMV3Y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем задании сказано:

> Удалить первое слово заданной строки. Разделителем слов считается
>   пробел

Что такое слово в контексте задания? Это последовательность символов, не включающая встроенные пробелы, не так ли?
Что означает первое слово? Это первая последовательность знаков в строке, которая начинается не с пробела, не так ли?

Поэтому для правильного решения задания, вы должны 1) пропустить в строке ведущие пробелы; 2) найти первый не пробельный символ. Он будет означать начало первого слова в строке; 3) найти окончание этого первого слова, то есть найти первый пробельный символ далее в строке; 4) удалить ведущие пробелы перед вторым словом в строке.

Последний пункт необязательный. Можно оставить ведущие пробелы перед вторым словом, так как в задании говорится, что нужно удалить лишь первое слово. Но даже здесь возникает вопрос, а удалять ли при этом ведущие пробелы перед самим первым словом, или их надо сохранить в выходной строке?

Очень важно формулировать задание так, чтобы не было неоднозначности.

Ниже показаны три подхода.

В первом подходе удаляется первое слово и все ведущие пробелы перед первым и вторым словами (для этого в исходной строке я добавил начальный пробел для наглядности).

Во втором подходе удаляется первое слово и ведущие пробелы, которые предшествуют только первому слову.

В третьем подходе удаляется только само первое слово. Все пробелы сохраняются в выходной строке.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
{   
    //  Removing the first word and all leading spaces
    const size_t N = 80;

    char str[N] = " faE,1*fe A.,.3iBVf Oq. e.of 43G.FW2,jiq,e[ qe";
    char token[N];

    size_t n = std::strspn( str, " " );
    n += std::strcspn( str + n, " " );
    n += std::strspn( str + n, " " );
    std::strcpy( token, str + n );

    std::cout << '\"' << str << '\"' << std::endl;
    std::cout << '\"' << token << '\"' << std::endl;
}
    std::cout << std::endl;
{   
    //  Removing the first word and all leading spaces that precede the first word
    const size_t N = 80;

    char str[N] = " faE,1*fe A.,.3iBVf Oq. e.of 43G.FW2,jiq,e[ qe";
    char token[N];

    size_t n = std::strspn( str, " " );
    n += std::strcspn( str + n, " " );
    std::strcpy( token, str + n );

    std::cout << '\"' << str << '\"' << std::endl;
    std::cout << '\"' << token << '\"' << std::endl;
}
    std::cout << std::endl;
{   
    //  Removing only the first word and keeping all embedded spaces
    const size_t N = 80;

    char str[N] = " faE,1*fe A.,.3iBVf Oq. e.of 43G.FW2,jiq,e[ qe";
    char token[N];

    size_t n = std::strspn( str, " " );
    strncpy( token, str, n );
    size_t m = n;
    n += std::strcspn( str + n, " " );
    std::strcpy( token + m, str + n );

    std::cout << '\"' << str << '\"' << std::endl;
    std::cout << '\"' << token << '\"' << std::endl;
}
    return 0;
}
```

Программа имеет следующий вывод на консоль

```
" faE,1*fe A.,.3iBVf Oq. e.of 43G.FW2,jiq,e[ qe"
"A.,.3iBVf Oq. e.of 43G.FW2,jiq,e[ qe"

" faE,1*fe A.,.3iBVf Oq. e.of 43G.FW2,jiq,e[ qe"
" A.,.3iBVf Oq. e.of 43G.FW2,jiq,e[ qe"

" faE,1*fe A.,.3iBVf Oq. e.of 43G.FW2,jiq,e[ qe"
"  A.,.3iBVf Oq. e.of 43G.FW2,jiq,e[ qe"
```

По этому выводу видны различия указанных трех подходов к решению задания.

Comment: Грамотный ответ. IMHO его можно чуть улучшить, акцентировав (в коде) вычисление длины первой порции пробелов, длины первого слова и длины пробелов перед вторым словом и все копирования делать исходя уже из этих величин.

Comment: @avp  Это можно рассматривать как дополнительные условия к заданию.:)

Comment: А можно как кодовый образец  всем тем, кто в будущем нагуглит Ваш ответ.

Comment: Нее, я не буду (в принципе не люблю править чужой текст, да и просто лень). / Короче, следующему поколению не повезло...

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;


char* sword_del(char* s){
   char* p, *t = s;

   while(isspace(*s))
       ++s;

   p = s;
   while(*p && ! isspace(*p))
       ++p;

   while((*s = *p) != '\0'){
       ++p;
       ++s;
   }
   return t;
}


int main(void){
    char s[] = "faE,1*fe A.,.3iBVf Oq. e.of 43G.FW2,jiq,e[ qe";
    cout << sword_del(s) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну, последний в sword_del() while можно записать и покороче: `while (*s++ = *p++);` (думаю, прямо из K&R -)).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str[80] = "faE,1*fe A.,.3iBVf Oq. e.of 43G.FW2,jiq,e[ qe";
    char token[80];

    cout << str << endl;

    strcpy(token, strstr(str, " "));

    cout << token << endl;
}
```

Comment: Когда же вы начнете читать документацию, а не изобретать велосипеды. И кстати, хватит писать по Сишному на плюсах. Для этого в плюсах есть std::string.

Comment: Ну и как это будет работать, если перед первым словом идут пробелы?